# Removing URL parameters

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I am passing some parameters from one page to another through session ,problem what I am facing is each parameters is getting reflected in the URL,which I think is not a correct way. So I want to remove all the parameters from the URL,while navigating to other page.

Please suggest me some way to archive so.

This is the URL what I am getting

```
http://localhost:58736/index.html#bankedit//10000422%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?PayeeId=4&BankName=State%20Bank%20%20
```

Code what I am using to navigate is:

```
cellTemplate: function (container, options) {$('<a/>').addClass('hyperlink')
       .text('Edit |')
       .on('click', function () {
            var Edit;
            Demo.app.navigate("bankedit/?AccountNumber=" + options.data.AccountNumber + "&PayeeId=" + options.data.PayeeId + "&BankName=" + options.data.BankName );  
            sessionStorage.setItem('AccountNumber', options.data.AccountNumber);
            sessionStorage.setItem('PayeeId', options.data.PayeeId);
            sessionStorage.setItem('BankName', options.data.BankName);
            sessionStorage.setItem('Type', "Edit");
      }).appendTo(container);

       $('<a/>').addClass('hyperlink')
           .text(' Delete')
           .on('click', function () {
                  options.component.removeRow(options.rowIndex);
           }).appendTo(container);
    }
```

And for retrieval of parameter values:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("BankName"),
```

in bankedit.js page

Comment: You mean on target page it should show only base url like *localhost/index.html* and not other parameters?

Comment: Yes exactly which I am not able to implement

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay. You can try `history` API to manipulate the URL shown in browser.

try following once loading is done:

```
var orig=document.location.href;
var noParam=urlWithoutParams.substring(0,urlWithoutParams.indexOf("#"));

history.replaceState({'Original':orig},'',noParam);
```

This will replace current href with one without any query string parameters. More information about history API is here at <kbd>[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the response,I tried to implement this,but  it is not working. Can you please suggest me some other way to perform so like Post method or something.

Comment: Is this single page app? Are you moving to `bankedit` page or only a hash change (part after #) occurs? If you navigate to next page then you need to run this history stuff on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Tkanks a lot for sharing your experience.I am able to solve it with session.   I just replaced `Demo.app.navigate("bankedit/?AccountNumber=" + options.data.AccountNumber + "&PayeeId=" + options.data.PayeeId + "&BankName=" + options.data.BankName );` with `PaMobile01.app.navigate("bankinformationedit/");`

And kept rest of my parameters in session